# Python performs append operation on wrong lists

Tags: dataframe, group-by

I created a method to group a Pandas DataFrame by month and store some general statistics.
When I run the method for the first time using two DataFrames the output is as expected, each list has 12 entries.

```
2021-01
1 1
2021-02
2 2
2021-03
3 3
2021-04
4 4
2021-05
5 5
2021-06
6 6
2021-07
7 7
2021-08
8 8
2021-09
9 9
2021-10
10 10
2021-11
11 11
2021-12
12 12
```

However, when I continue execution with the next two DataFrames it starts adding the values percentage and fire_len to both percentages and absolute, resulting in lists containing 24 elements in stead of 12.

```
2021-01
2 2
2021-02
4 4
2021-03
6 6
2021-04
8 8
2021-05
10 10
2021-06
12 12
2021-07
14 14
2021-08
16 16
2021-09
18 18
2021-10
20 20
2021-11
22 22
2021-12
24 24
```

The second time I execute the method I omit the total and dates arguments. Can anyone help?

````
def group_df(df1, df2, percentages: [], absolute: [], total=None, dates=None):
    for key, item in df1:
        print(key)
        fire_len = len(df1.get_group(key).index)
        total_len = len(df2.get_group(key).index)
        percentage = (fire_len / total_len) * 100
        percentages.append(percentage)
        absolute.append(fire_len)
        if dates is not None:
            dates.append(key)
        if total is not None:
            total.append(total_len)

        print(len(percentages), len(absolute))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by putting all lists in a dict and passing that in stead of the lists separately. Not sure why it resolved the issue but it did.
It turns out that having duplicate entries wasn't the only problem, some lists were also wiped. Using a dict apparently prevents this.